# Improper HTTPS - Connection only partially encrypted

Tags: bug, status-planned, ssl

When I access Stack Overflow via HTTPS, my browser (Firefox) complains that not all elements (images) of the web page portal are loaded via HTTPS, leading to some insecurity. Can this be fixed please?

Comment: HTTPS is not yet fully deployed. It's a work-in-progress.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is first brought up in the question: [Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites) in december 2011.

And re-surfaced earlier this year in [Roadmap for HTTPS/SSL support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226030/roadmap-for-https-ssl-support)

[Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) wrote the [steps needed to implement SSL support across the network](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) and [Stackoverflow.com: the road to SSL](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/)

There are similar posts on MSE like [Firefox SSL warning for data.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237481/firefox-ssl-warning-for-data-stackexchange-com) and [SSL Errors on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215414/ssl-errors-on-stack-exchange?rq=1)

The team is aware and is working on it...

Comment: there's more links than anything else in this answer :0

Comment: @lostsock I'll do everything for easy rep...oh wait, this is meta...

Answer (score -4):

This error is due to the avatar images being loaded over http

Things like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/te0lD.png

See that flower? Yup - That's not secured, and that's why your Firefox is complaining.

Interestingly enough, that flower is being loaded from https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj33e.png?s=32&g=1, and there IS a secure version of this at https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj33e.png?s=32&g=1

---

Ok - The avatar images - My mistake.

To those down-voting me - From the Firefox Console

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MePij.png

Comment: It's nothing to do with Gravatar. That image is hosted by SE in their Imgur account.

Comment: I can only repeat **this is nothing to do with Gravatar**.

Comment: Edited the original reply - Thanks.

Comment: You're still saying that it's "due to the Gravatar avatar images" and "if it's something on Gravatar's side". These are incorrect statements. The images are being hosted by Imgur in SE's non-expiring account. It's **these** images that are being loaded over HTTP not HTTPS. If you look at the images actually hosted by Gravatar you'll see that they *are* loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: I added a second edit to clarify the first edit, as well as edited the original post. I did not wish to originally edit the original post as that would subsequently invalidate the subsequent comments, hence the "- Edit" text as opposed to simply editing the comment outright...