# Might my connection to SE sites be MITM'ed?

Tags: support, security

I have noticed for the past week or so that I'm often surprisingly "logged out" of SO and other SE network sites.

Additionally, even when I log in I'm on an HTTP, not HTTPS, connection. When I try to force HTTPS by adding the 's' into the protocol, Firefox shows the warning icon and comments that "This website does not supply ownership information."

**Might connections to Stack Overflow be subject to a [Man In The Middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)?**

Interestingly, I've noticed this from both my work machine and my home machine, which are on different ISPs.

Comment: Independently of whether there was a MITM attack, "*This website does not supply ownership information*" is not necessarily a problem (see [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/14061/2435)). It's the following message in that box that indicates a problem: "*The connection to this website is not fully secure because it contains unencrypted elements [...]*". That's just due to mixed content, which shouldn't be there when HTTPS is implemented properly. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268249/372643) too (in particular "status-planned").

Comment: Sounds like you might be having the same problem I reported here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267977/temporarily-lost-login-while-being-active.

Comment: @Bruno, Reto: Thanks. That is very likely the cause.

Comment: I've noticed the same behaviour, in my case it's because I had stackauth.com cookies white listed, but the authorization cookies are now coming from stackoverflow.com

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but the network-wide login doesn't work for me as of yesterday...