# How to control auto migration from the http secure to the default http while browsing SO

Tags: discussion

This question is not duplicate to this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268249/improper-https-connection-only-partially-encrypted) as in that question they were some errors that used to be displayed while browsing SO on a secure site. Whereas I do not get any such errors on my Internet Explorer browser v11.0.9

After following this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites) I agree that https is not yet fully accomplished but when I manually enter https instead of the http in the Internet Explorer I get the  SO site(I don't get any errors like incomplete HTTPs or the browser complaining about invalid secure connection etc.), But in some cases when I click on some topic in page /chat then It again migrates me to the default http site.

How can control this auto migration? Isn't there any way that I can only load https only everywhere on SO

Answer (score 1):

There is no SE provided way to accomplish this. However, you could write your own script to change any http link to https. Or you could find a browser plugin, like HTTPS Everywhere, to do it for you.